# render with no shadows like in solid mode

Tags: rendering, animation, shadows

It is possible to render a final animation with objects to look like when in solid mode and no shadows etc? How could I do that?

Comment: Use the [OpenGL render Active Viewport](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/opengl.html) button in the *3D View* window header at the bottom

Comment: Shall I have a lamp on the scene for that?

Comment: Depends on what look you want to achieve. In theory no, lamps have no effect in the viewport anyway, if you are using Cycles. Unless you are in Blender Internal/GLSL rendered mode where lamp shading is supported

Comment: It's possibile with the 2.93 version? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: Yes, you can still render the viewport view

Comment: There is no `OpenGL Render Image` option now. But u can still use `.sl` file in studio lighing and use `Viewport Render Image` button or Workbench render engine.