# Render with same output as "solid" viewport

Tags: rendering

I'd like to know how I could render a picture that looks the same as what I get in the main viewport (the "solid" view). I tried to play with "Shadeless" and "Toon" color, but I'm not convinced by the result. Indeed, "shadeless" renders the 3 faces with the exact same color, while I'd like to make a difference between faces (like in the solid viewport).

How could I do that? Thanks!

-- EDIT --
I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73108/render-with-no-shadows-like-in-solid-mode) that proposes to use the "OpenGL render active viewport" in the 3D View window header at the bottom , and it's quite a good idea. However, I'd like to know if I can go further and customize a bit this render (because for now I've zero choice on the render), plug it in composing nodes, customize the background... For instance, with the current method it's not possible to have complex materials with pictures, gradient… And also the background can't be set to transparent. One of the possible applications would be to do something like the picture page 4 of [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms9735.pdf) for example.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but perhaps a hint: in the 3d "solid" viewport there's a default (hidden) lighting that heavily influences how the scene is rendered by opengl. The user preferences have settings about diffuse/specular colors and direction for 3 lights, and you can also edit them interactively:

[image]

So, you could try a lighting setup that acts in the same or similar way, to render it, perhaps: the position of those lights is not accessible, though through the blender user interface (it could be possible to read those light position/direction through python, perhaps, but I'm not sure at all)